# Problems with namespaces in KnowRob

Tags: knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to follow the tutorial on [reasoning about actions](http://www.knowrob.org/doc/reasoning_about_actions) on the KnowRob website.

As suggested in the tutorial, I execute

```
$ roscd knowrob_basics_tutorial
$ rosrun rosprolog rosprolog knowrob_basics_tutorial
?- owl_parse('owl/pancake-making.owl', false, false, true).
```

and get a very hopeful

```
true.
```

I then proceed with

```
?- class_properties(pancake:'MakingPancakes', knowrob:subAction, Sub).
```

that unfortunately answers with

```
ERROR: namespace `pancake' does not exist
^  Exception: (11) setup_call_catcher_cleanup('$expand':'$set_source_module'(user, user), '$expand':expand_goal(class_properties(pancake:'MakingPancakes', knowrob:subAction, _G239), _G303, user, [user, system]), _G373, '$expand':'$set_source_module'(_G328, user)) ?
```

The namespace is correctly included in the OWl file

```
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns         ="&pancake;"
    xmlns:pancake ="&pancake;"
    xml:base      ="&pancake;"
    xmlns:knowrob ="&knowrob;"
    [...] >
```

so it's really hard for me to understand what's going on.
How do I ensure the pancake namespace is correctly included? Is there a way for me to *print out* all the namespaces?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/93061/problems-with-namespaces-in-knowrob/) by [micpalmia](https://answers.ros.org/users/6343/micpalmia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2013-10-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [micpalmia](https://answers.ros.org/users/6343/micpalmia/) on 2013-10-22**:
Turns out that if I use the whole class name, without abbreviating with the shortened namespace, everything works. Not sure how I should specify the namespace in prolog anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please update knowrob_tutorials or comment the include of 'tabletop_obj' in prolog/init.pl.in (and rosmake the package again).

Namespaces that are used in Prolog queries need to be defined in Prolog in addition to the OWL namespace definition. This is correctly done in prolog/init.pl using the following statement:
:- rdf_db:rdf_register_ns(pancake, 'http://ias.cs.tum.edu/kb/pancake-making.owl#', [keep(true)]).

If this does not work, I'd expect that you got error messages when loading Prolog saying that tabletop_obj could not be found, with the result that the init.pl is not loaded completely.

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2013-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [micpalmia](https://answers.ros.org/users/6343/micpalmia/) on 2013-10-22**:
I guess the edit has to be made in the `init.pl` file, not the `init.pl.in` file. If I edit the latter (or clone the package from github as it is now) the problem is not solved.

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2013-10-22**:
The init.pl is generated from the init.pl.in file by rosmake, therefore you have to edit that file. Otherwise your changes would be overridden by the next rosmake.

Are there any error messages or warnings during startup?

**Comment by [micpalmia](https://answers.ros.org/users/6343/micpalmia/) on 2013-10-22**:
sry, didn't take the time to fully understand this. got it, works fine.